# Excel - How to build pick lists dynamically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's worksheet A:

```
Parent    Kid        Age
------    ---        ---
John      Scott      5
John      Lucas      7
John      Elisabeth  12
Victoria  Jason      3
Victoria  Amy        5
Jenifer   Ashely     13
Jenifer   Jared      17
```

And worksheet B:

```
Parent    Kid        Team
------    ---        ----
John      Elisabeth  Lions
Jenifer   Ashely     Sharks
Jenifer   Jared      Panters
```

In worksheet B, I want my users to be able to choose the kid's name from a pick list (using data validation). The values of that pick list should be driven by the kid names entered for this parent in worksheet A. For example, if I select cell A2, the pick list should contain:

```
Scott
Lucas
Elisabeth
```

Can I do this with a regular formula or should I use VBA?

Comment: Why don't you use a filter, then choose from the dropdown the parent's name?

Comment: Is it possible that parents are not grouped (eg. John -> child1, Tom -> child2, John->child3, Tom->child4)? If not you may set a dynamic range name on Worksheet A children list, referring to start given by input in Worksheet B, and allow only list from this named range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a named range called `Kids` with the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(WA!$B$2, MATCH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()), WA!$A$2:$A$8, 0) - 1, 0, COUNTIF(WA!$A$2:$A$200, INDIRECT("A" & ROW())), 1)
```

And then set the validation list to `=Kids`.

In case someone wonderes, I used `INDIRECT("A" & ROW())` because just using A1 returned an error (my excel-fu is not strong enough to understand why). Doing WB!A1 worked fine but I did not want to go that route because I have to reuse that name range in other worksheets of that workbook. If there's a better way, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: What was this error? Circular reference?

Comment: It doesn't tell. It happens in the Data Validation dialog box when I set =Kids as the source of the list and click OK. I just get an error saying that the formula evals to an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure whether it is the simplest way, but if it is sure, that parents are grouped in the Worksheet A (so it's like you've written, and not like eg.

```
John     Scott
Victoria Jason
John     Lucas
```

), you may consider using this solution (I assume your worksheet data A begin with "John" in A2 cell, `WA` stands for Worksheet A, and `WB` stands for worksheet B):

First of all, add another column, called offset in WA. Because "Age" is `C` column, I put it in `D` column. The formula is `=Row(A2)-Row($A$2)` and is propagated downwards. You should get `0`, `1`, `2` ... These are offsets of each row in relation to the first one.

We will use this value for our offset using `VLOOKUP` function. In WB, let's say you input your parent's name in cell `A1`, in `B1` we will get the child's name(s). So in auxiliary column, say `C`, we put the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A1; WA!$A$2:$D$xxx; 4; FALSE)
```

the parameters mean:

- `A1` is the cell value you're searching - the parent's name
- `WA!$A$2:$D$xxx` denotes range where you search (replace `xxx` with how many rows you get)
- `4` means that we want to retrieve 4th column value, that is `WA!D` in this case, and this is our offset
- `FALSE` means that we want to perform exact search as the `WA!A` column is (or might be) not sorted.

The value you get is the value where your range should begin. Now we need to find its ending, this means how many rows there are. The simplest way can be adding another column in WA, say `E`, where we put a simple formula counting how many children a parent has:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$xxx; A2)
```

In your example you will get `3`, `3`, `3`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`.

You should to copy this value to WB, column `D`, using again:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1; WA!$A$2:$E$xxx; 5; FALSE)
```

Now, in WB, we have in column `A` parent's name, in column `B` we insert a child, in column `C` there is offset of the first child of the parent, and in column `D` number of children the parent has.

Now go to the name manager and add new name `Kids` covering the range:

```
=OFFSET(WA!$B$2:$B$xxx; WB!D1; 0; WB!E1)
```

where parameters mean:

- `WA$B$2:$B$xxx` - is the range containing child names,
- `WB!D1` (note: it's relative!) is the offset, so where child list starts in the before-said range in WA,
- `0`  means we don't want to make any offset in columns,
- `WB!E1` says how many rows we want to get (ie. how many children).

Having this `Kids` name, you add now in `WB!B1` the Data Validation, set to list and the source is `=Kids`. Now propagate it downwards.

That's all.

If your data in WA do not contain grouped parents, you are able to get this by sorting them.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. It provided the inspiration behind the solution I finally used.